# Magnus series expansion

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

In the theory of the Magnus series expansion, it can be found that

$$
\Omega(t) = \int_0^t A(\tau)d\tau - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \left[ \int_0^\tau A(\sigma)d\sigma, A(\tau) \right]d\tau + \frac{1}{4}\int_0^t \left[ \int_0^\tau \left[ \int_0^\sigma A(\mu)d\mu, A(\sigma) \right] d\sigma , A(\tau) \right] d\tau + \frac{1}{12} \int_0^t \left[ \int_0^\tau A(\sigma) d\sigma, \left[ \int_0^\tau A(\mu) d\mu , A(\tau) \right] \right] d\tau + \ldots
$$

where $A(t)$ is a matrix in function of $t$ and $[A,B]$ represents the commutator for two matrices $A$ and $B$. We can use $\Omega(t)$ for numerical methods of the form $Y(t) = exp(\Omega(t))Y_0$.

By making use of the two-stage Gauss quadrature we can approximate the integrals above, which results in

$$
Y_{n+1} = exp\left(\frac{h}{2} (A_1+A_2) + \frac{\sqrt{3}h^2}{12}[A_2,A_1]\right)Y_n
$$

where $A_i = A(t_n + c_ih)$ and $c_i$ are the coëfficiënts of the two-stage Gauss quadrature.

The first term of the $exp$, $\frac{h}{2} (A_1+A_2)$, results from computing $\int_0^t A(\tau)d\tau$,

$$
\int_0^t A(\tau)d\tau =^{t := \tau h} h \left( \int_0^1 \frac{\tau - c_2}{c_1-c_2} d\tau A_1 + \int_0^1 \frac{\tau-c_1}{c_2-c_1} d\tau A_2 \right) = h \left( \frac{1}{2}A_1 + \frac{1}{2}A_2 \right)
$$

The second term, $\frac{\sqrt{3}h^2}{12}[A_2,A_1]$, should return by computing the integral with the $\frac{1}{2}$ coëfficiënt, but I'm stuck during the computation of the integral...

$$
- \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \left[ \int_0^\tau A(\sigma)d\sigma, A(\tau) \right] d\tau\\
= \ldots ? \, \, \, \quad \quad \quad \, \, \, \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \,
$$